# PHP assert : display file content in error message

Tags: php, file, assert

I am studying some exploits of web server, and I found an assert in which I can inject some php code.
I found that the following code

```
assert(file_get_contents('file.txt') !== null)
```

works as I expected: the `file_get_contents()` is executed, and its result is passed in the assert. However, if I make it fail like so

```
assert(file_get_contents('file.txt') === null)
```

The `file_get_contents()` result is not interpreted and thus not shown in the error message.

```
Warning: assert(): assert(file_get_contents('file.txt') === null) failed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/assert.php on line 3
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could get the file content, assuming that I can only do it in an assert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that are wondering how this could be done, I found a solution. `file_get_contents()` does not display directly the content of a file, you have to `echo` it to show it.

However, the function `readfile()` does it perfectly, it just displays directly the file's content.

So just call the assert like so:

```
assert(readfile('file.txt') === null)
```